# Sample Dataset into equal positive and negative samples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am trying to get a sample of huge dataset where number of +ve samples = num of -ve sample in a memory efficient way.

the ratio of data is 4 : 2 +ve to -ve so i am trying to make a sample where the data would be in the ratio of 2 : 2

```
    A   B   C class   
0   0   1   2   0
1   3   4   5   0
2   6   7   8   1
3   9   10  11  1
4   12  13  14  1
5   15  16  17  1
```

Desired output :

```
    A   B   C   class   
0   0   1   2   0
1   3   4   5   0
2   6   7   8   1
3   9   10  11  1
```

I tried to sample it using python code using pandas value_counts func but it is not memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
positive=data[data['class']==0]
negative=data[data['class']==1].sample(n=positive.shape[0])
final=pd.concat([positive,negative])
```

or

```
positive_len=np.sum(data['class']==0) #gives the number of rows with class=0
final=data.sort_values('class')[:2*positive_len] #sort values. now rows with class 0 are on the top, rows with class 1 are on the bottom. pick top 2* length of positive.
```

Comment: Dear sam, this would sample the data in to equal parts but the whole data would have to be memory for this to work..

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes i agree but.... its hard for me to manipulate data and create temporary variables due to memory constraint, So as of now i think chunking(while importing csv) is one of the possible solutions,I am working on it and will update the question once i have the solution, meanwhile i'm also looking for other possible leads...

Comment: @Ajay Pandas, on its own, is designed for in-memory operations. There are several tools (often used in conjunction) for out-of-memory operations: HDF5, pyTables, dask.dataframe.

I would also suggest that storing an array of integers in a pandas dataframe isn't efficient. Numpy arrays should give better performance.